# web api - list variables on a class

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm doing some code in my web api and i want to list all variables in a model class, and show them

Here is the web api's code:

```
   //Method to list all the variables from the class Hello
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/listOfVariables")]
    public IEnumerable<String> listOfVariables()
    {
        return typeof(Hello).GetFields()
                                    .Select(field => field.Name)
                                    .ToList(); 
    }
```

Model class

```
  public class Hello
     {
       public int HelloId { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

And the web api config:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and when i use the following url: 
           http://localhost:1861/api/listOfVariables

i get this information:

```
  <ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
```

Can someone help me? I'm new to .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Hello` class doesn't have any fields, so what you're seeing is an empty list.  The class has *properties* instead.  You can use `GetProperties()` to fetch those.

To illustrate:

```
class Hello
{
    public int HelloId; // field
}

class Hello
{
    public int HelloId { get; set; } // property
}
```

Comment: Its correct. Thanks for the explanation and for your time! i really appreciate. I will accept your answer as the solution